# Setting/Un-Setting Service Lock Database Schema Property Using ArcGIS API for Python

Tags: arcgis-python-api

Is there a way to set/unset a service `Lock Database Schema` using ArcGIS ArcGIS API for Python?

[image]

Comment: Check this out https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-server-with-javascript-api-questions/disable-schema-locking-on-multiple-published/td-p/793132